# Android studio - How to pass context value from a fragment to another activity?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-context

I have a fragment 'X' whose parent activity is 'A'.

I have another activity 'B' which contains a method 'getData()'; This activity also has its own parameterized constructor in which object of Context is being passed to this constructor.

Activity B:-

```
public class B
{
  Context _context;
  String val="XYZ";

  public B(Context context)
  {
    this._context = context;
    //Rest of the code
  }
  public String getData()
  {
    return val;
  }
}
```

My program requires me to call getData() method of activity 'B' in fragment 'X'

Fragment X :-

```
public class X extends Fragment implements 
{
  String name;

  Context context=getActivity().getApplicationContext();

  B obj1=new B(context); 
  //i have passed Context object from fragment X to Activity B

  ButtonClickEvent(..)
  {
    name=obj1.getData();
    //Rest of the code
  }
}
```

The issue is arising while launching Fragment X; the error is related to Context object, I dont understand what exatcly is the issue; Suggestions are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: Please post the error? Besides, why are you instantiating the activity with a constructor? Also, there should be some other way to get the data than to create a new instance of the activity and then getting its data from a fragment that is not attached to it. This could lead to subtle yet fatal bugs later on as your app grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two likely definitions:

- `getActivity()` in a Fragment returns the `Activity` the `Fragment` is currently associated with. (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()).
- `getActivity()` is user-defined.

So create a `constructor` in `Activity` and pass `getAcivity()` there to get context.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion helped! context=getActivity().getApplicationContext(); I wrote this statement in OnCreateView() and it worked!